# Looking for peers, no mining in a private Ethereum network

Tags: go-ethereum

I am learning Ethereum from scratch by deploying my small local network.
I can follow along the tutorial until I reach [part9](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eYj0vPcZAs8&list=PLkM0MH7Grb25poKEiId5pEQg-OzLQRNM4&index=9&ab_channel=Blockholic)
I run the bnode(aka boot node), node1, and node2 respectively. Here is the screen terminal of them.

Here is my software spec.

```bash
geth version
Geth
Version: 1.10.11-stable
Architecture: amd64
Go Version: go1.17.2
Operating System: darwin
GOPATH=
GOROOT=go
bash
```

OSX 11.6

`boot node`

```bash
❯ bootnode -nodekey boot.key './boot.key' -verbosity 7 -addr '127.0.0.1:30301'
enode://6179844557b839de35fa75c13500ad875a4999c47afe97034e4adfba2284cdc5cd82a50a586c7f0e5f5cd08736ac5421976c5352d78b73a7339bc3e69978d084@127.0.0.1:0?discport=30301
Note: you're using cmd/bootnode, a developer tool.
We recommend using a regular node as bootstrap node for production deployments.
INFO [11-05|14:12:31.316] New local node record                    seq=1,636,096,351,316 id=4b67a546d344b4d6 ip=<nil> udp=0 tcp=0
```

`node1`

```bash
geth --networkid 14333 --datadir './data' --bootnodes enode://6179844557b839de35fa75c13500ad875a4999c47afe97034e4adfba2284cdc5cd82a50a586c7f0e5f5cd08736ac5421976c5352d78b73a7339bc3e69978d084@127.0.0.1:30301 --port 30303 --ipcdisable --syncmode full --http --allow-insecure-unlock --http.corsdomain '*' --http.port 8545 --unlock 0x79b86A24826d6dA4863de235a54c30386065846F --password password.txt --mine console
```

```bash
INFO [11-05|14:13:35.080] Maximum peer count                       ETH=50 LES=0 total=50
INFO [11-05|14:13:35.081] Set global gas cap                       cap=50,000,000
INFO [11-05|14:13:35.081] Allocated trie memory caches             clean=154.00MiB dirty=256.00MiB
INFO [11-05|14:13:35.081] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/Users/sarit/study/try_vyper/node1/data/geth/chaindata cache=512.00MiB handles=5120
INFO [11-05|14:13:35.233] Opened ancient database                  database=/Users/sarit/study/try_vyper/node1/data/geth/chaindata/ancient readonly=false
INFO [11-05|14:13:35.236] Initialised chain configuration          config="{ChainID: 1 Homestead: 1150000 DAO: 1920000 DAOSupport: true EIP150: 2463000 EIP155: 2675000 EIP158: 2675000 Byzantium: 4370000 Constantinople: 7280000 Petersburg: 7280000 Istanbul: 9069000, Muir Glacier: 9200000, Berlin: 12244000, London: 12965000, Engine: ethash}"
INFO [11-05|14:13:35.238] Disk storage enabled for ethash caches   dir=/Users/sarit/study/try_vyper/node1/data/geth/ethash count=3
INFO [11-05|14:13:35.238] Disk storage enabled for ethash DAGs     dir=/Users/sarit/Library/Ethash count=2
INFO [11-05|14:13:35.238] Initialising Ethereum protocol           network=14333 dbversion=8
INFO [11-05|14:13:35.242] Loaded most recent local header          number=0 hash=d4e567..cb8fa3 td=17,179,869,184 age=52y7mo6d
INFO [11-05|14:13:35.242] Loaded most recent local full block      number=0 hash=d4e567..cb8fa3 td=17,179,869,184 age=52y7mo6d
INFO [11-05|14:13:35.242] Loaded most recent local fast block      number=0 hash=d4e567..cb8fa3 td=17,179,869,184 age=52y7mo6d
INFO [11-05|14:13:35.243] Loaded local transaction journal         transactions=0 dropped=0
INFO [11-05|14:13:35.243] Regenerated local transaction journal    transactions=0 accounts=0
INFO [11-05|14:13:35.244] Gasprice oracle is ignoring threshold set threshold=2
WARN [11-05|14:13:35.244] Unclean shutdown detected                booted=2021-11-05T13:02:15+0700 age=1h11m20s
WARN [11-05|14:13:35.244] Unclean shutdown detected                booted=2021-11-05T13:08:59+0700 age=1h4m36s
INFO [11-05|14:13:35.244] Starting peer-to-peer node               instance=Geth/v1.10.11-stable/darwin-amd64/go1.17.2
INFO [11-05|14:13:35.409] New local node record                    seq=1,636,092,136,038 id=851fb35f8fe28fc4 ip=127.0.0.1 udp=30303 tcp=30303
INFO [11-05|14:13:35.411] Started P2P networking                   self=enode://e311067696d9baa62b8e8348aaa11c6f069e0d5072dfa51157c645971bc46c45de4d949cb6ecee477366b9bf4ae1132cf439c3683e230b3e947337c6dcaa6ae1@127.0.0.1:30303
INFO [11-05|14:13:35.413] HTTP server started                      endpoint=127.0.0.1:8545 prefix= cors=* vhosts=localhost
INFO [11-05|14:13:36.149] Unlocked account                         address=0x79b86A24826d6dA4863de235a54c30386065846F
INFO [11-05|14:13:36.149] Transaction pool price threshold updated price=1,000,000,000
INFO [11-05|14:13:36.149] Updated mining threads                   threads=0
INFO [11-05|14:13:36.149] Transaction pool price threshold updated price=1,000,000,000
INFO [11-05|14:13:36.149] Etherbase automatically configured       address=0x79b86A24826d6dA4863de235a54c30386065846F
INFO [11-05|14:13:36.149] Commit new mining work                   number=1 sealhash=f2e430..ddb5ef uncles=0 txs=0 gas=0 fees=0 elapsed="185.63µs"
Welcome to the Geth JavaScript console!

instance: Geth/v1.10.11-stable/darwin-amd64/go1.17.2
coinbase: 0x79b86a24826d6da4863de235a54c30386065846f
at block: 0 (Thu Jan 01 1970 07:00:00 GMT+0700 (+07))
 datadir: /Users/sarit/study/try_vyper/node1/data
 modules: admin:1.0 debug:1.0 eth:1.0 ethash:1.0 miner:1.0 net:1.0 personal:1.0 rpc:1.0 txpool:1.0 web3:1.0

To exit, press ctrl-d or type exit
> INFO [11-05|14:13:45.972] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=1 static=0
INFO [11-05|14:13:56.043] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=0 static=0
```

And last line repeat forever

`node2`

```bash
 geth --networkid 14333 --datadir './data' --bootnodes enode://6179844557b839de35fa75c13500ad875a4999c47afe97034e4adfba2284cdc5cd82a50a586c7f0e5f5cd08736ac5421976c5352d78b73a7339bc3e69978d084@127.0.0.1:30301 --port 30304 --ipcdisable --syncmode full --http --allow-insecure-unlock --http.corsdomain '*' --http.port 8546 --unlock 0x7Bf2fb865F9bF6Da20Cb7758D2671728eE38Ec0C --password password.txt console
INFO [11-05|14:14:30.263] Maximum peer count                       ETH=50 LES=0 total=50
INFO [11-05|14:14:30.265] Set global gas cap                       cap=50,000,000
INFO [11-05|14:14:30.265] Allocated trie memory caches             clean=154.00MiB dirty=256.00MiB
INFO [11-05|14:14:30.266] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/Users/sarit/study/try_vyper/node2/data/geth/chaindata cache=512.00MiB handles=5120
INFO [11-05|14:14:30.444] Opened ancient database                  database=/Users/sarit/study/try_vyper/node2/data/geth/chaindata/ancient readonly=false
INFO [11-05|14:14:30.451] Initialised chain configuration          config="{ChainID: 1 Homestead: 1150000 DAO: 1920000 DAOSupport: true EIP150: 2463000 EIP155: 2675000 EIP158: 2675000 Byzantium: 4370000 Constantinople: 7280000 Petersburg: 7280000 Istanbul: 9069000, Muir Glacier: 9200000, Berlin: 12244000, London: 12965000, Engine: ethash}"
INFO [11-05|14:14:30.455] Disk storage enabled for ethash caches   dir=/Users/sarit/study/try_vyper/node2/data/geth/ethash count=3
INFO [11-05|14:14:30.455] Disk storage enabled for ethash DAGs     dir=/Users/sarit/Library/Ethash count=2
INFO [11-05|14:14:30.455] Initialising Ethereum protocol           network=14333 dbversion=8
INFO [11-05|14:14:30.477] Loaded most recent local header          number=0 hash=d4e567..cb8fa3 td=17,179,869,184 age=52y7mo6d
INFO [11-05|14:14:30.478] Loaded most recent local full block      number=0 hash=d4e567..cb8fa3 td=17,179,869,184 age=52y7mo6d
INFO [11-05|14:14:30.478] Loaded most recent local fast block      number=0 hash=d4e567..cb8fa3 td=17,179,869,184 age=52y7mo6d
INFO [11-05|14:14:30.479] Loaded local transaction journal         transactions=0 dropped=0
INFO [11-05|14:14:30.479] Regenerated local transaction journal    transactions=0 accounts=0
INFO [11-05|14:14:30.480] Gasprice oracle is ignoring threshold set threshold=2
INFO [11-05|14:14:30.481] Starting peer-to-peer node               instance=Geth/v1.10.11-stable/darwin-amd64/go1.17.2
INFO [11-05|14:14:30.602] New local node record                    seq=1,636,093,485,881 id=48793918926338cc ip=127.0.0.1 udp=30304 tcp=30304
INFO [11-05|14:14:30.602] Started P2P networking                   self=enode://6db0da7a72cd3465901eb8f5aa1bb9a168912bc4b9042536da624fa923fd27f7d131c8f940828e2ccc2fd7edb84bb8c11335f43bb5ddb6108410c6064fd3605e@127.0.0.1:30304
INFO [11-05|14:14:30.606] HTTP server started                      endpoint=127.0.0.1:8546 prefix= cors=* vhosts=localhost
INFO [11-05|14:14:31.363] Unlocked account                         address=0x7Bf2fb865F9bF6Da20Cb7758D2671728eE38Ec0C
INFO [11-05|14:14:31.401] Etherbase automatically configured       address=0x7Bf2fb865F9bF6Da20Cb7758D2671728eE38Ec0C
Welcome to the Geth JavaScript console!

instance: Geth/v1.10.11-stable/darwin-amd64/go1.17.2
coinbase: 0x7bf2fb865f9bf6da20cb7758d2671728ee38ec0c
at block: 0 (Thu Jan 01 1970 07:00:00 GMT+0700 (+07))
 datadir: /Users/sarit/study/try_vyper/node2/data
 modules: admin:1.0 debug:1.0 eth:1.0 ethash:1.0 miner:1.0 net:1.0 personal:1.0 rpc:1.0 txpool:1.0 web3:1.0

To exit, press ctrl-d or type exit
> INFO [11-05|14:14:40.675] Looking for peers                        peercount=1 tried=1 static=0
INFO [11-05|14:14:50.757] Looking for peers                        peercount=1 tried=0 static=0
```

Also last line repeat forever

I have checked with the document that from the YouTube I have to replace `rpc` with `http`. [doc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69463898/flag-provided-but-not-defined-rpc)

Comment: Nevermind. I skip this task and start using simple single node from this YT. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m_Ry0LZjoRQ&ab_channel=ChainSkills